# Java XPath syntax with string variable within XPath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to grab a dynamic element with an incremental number in the XPath.

Here is the HTML of the element that I am trying to find:

```
<a class="delete_link" data-hide-id="list_169" data-delete-action="/panel/menuitem/menudelete/id/169" href="#">Delete</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=list_"+pageID+"")).click();
```

where `pageID` is the string number following "list_"

I cannot seem to get the syntax right for it to find this element. I would normally just find it by ID, but this element doesn't have a normal ID identifier as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the wrong attribute name `@id` instead of `@data-hide-id`.
Try the following XPath expression:

```
"//a[@data-hide-id = 'list_" + pageID + "']"
```

In a whole command this could look like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-hide-id = 'list_" + pageID + "']")).click();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to be missing one quotation as there are 7 in the whole string, and doesnt like that `pageID` is a string instead of an int

I had to make pageID a string because of how I pull it to account for the dynamic element. 

Here is the code for that:


    `WebElement activeName = 
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'link-active')]"));
  String pageName = activeName.getAttribute("name");
  String pageID = pageName.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
  System.out.println(pageID);`

Sorry I dont know how to block code in comments

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed the quotes including a single quote `'`. Now there are even counts of quotes in the expression.

Comment: Thanks! That works. So the double quotes go around the inserted object within the xpath value single quotes. Got it! Much love dude